# Spell Check Plugin for Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

I am looking for a spell check plug in for firefox, what is a good one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox [has a spell checker built in](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/features/).

[This article describes it a little.](http://www.ehow.com/how_4509596_use-firefox-spell-checker.html)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the language, of course :)

In any case you are looking for the [Dictionaries & Language Packs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/browse/type:3) on the Firefox Addons website.

Meanwhile, other external programs integrate well with Firefox. Programs such as [Babylon](http://www.babylon.com/) and, to a lesser extent, [WordWeb Pro](http://wordweb.info/free/). But unless the language you are interested in is not well served by the Firefox addons, I see no need to go this route.